# Null query result cant fetch in Select query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, null

I have below query which i am  trying to run but not returning the expected result. The `ISIN` field value which is Null in `EXPORT_BB` is also getting ignore and not showing the result with the condition given in `NOT IN` clause. The export_blacklist has only one row value and which is not Null but still i dont for what reason the null value is getting ignored.

```
Select * from EXPORT_BB where ISIN NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            ISIN
        FROM
            export_blacklist);
```

If i run only select query without the NOT IN clause then i can see values which is `NULL` for  `ISIN` field.

JUst for test i tried below query and its also resulting nothing. Is it bug in Oracle 18c or something is missing?

```
select 'null is not in set' from dual where null not in (select 1 from dual);
```

Comment: You need to say where `isin is null or isin not in...`  `null` is neither `in` nor `not in` any result set...

Answer (score 2):

Any comparison of `NULL` with `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>` or in a `IN` or `NOT IN` clause will return `NULL`, so that row is not included in the results (because only rows for which the returned value is `TRUE` will be included in the results).
Change your code with a condition for the case that `ISIN` is `NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM EXPORT_BB 
WHERE ISIN NOT IN (SELECT ISIN FROM export_blacklist)
OR ISIN IS NULL
```

Comment: I guess that if there's a NULL in EXPORT_BB and there isn't in EXPORT_BLACKLIST, the OP won't want that row...

Comment: @btpys read the question again: *The ISIN field value which is Null in EXPORT_BB is also getting ignore and not showing the result with the condition given in NOT IN clause.* the OP wants to see the NULLs

Comment: sry, u're right, I mean't if there's also NULL in EXPORT_BLACKLIST. So if there are NULL in both tables, I guess the OP won't want to see it.

Comment: *The export_blacklist has only one row value and which is not Null* from the question

Comment: Yep, that's in the question, but I go further, the OP is treating NULLs as regular values, so I was guessing that if there are NULLs in both tables, he would't want it.

Answer (score 1):

NULL values doesn't work with `NOT IN` it's the normal behaviour.

You have to convert the NULL to another value to be able to operate with it or use `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL`

```
Select * from EXPORT_BB where NVL(ISIN, 999999) NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            NVL(ISIN, 999999)
        FROM
            export_blacklist);
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing to a null value in Oracle always returns false.

Is NULL >= 1? No.

Is NULL < 1? No.

Is NULL in your set? Regardless of what your set is, the answer is no.

Is NULL not in your set? Again, no.

Comment: . . Technically, it returns `NULL` which `WHERE` clauses treat as false.

Comment: NULLS would be considered in the case of a NOT EXISTS scenario

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behaviour. NOt related to 18c it is the same way from Oracle 7 onwards

NOT IN doesnt consider nulls.

NOT EXISTS does consider nulls.

Consider the following example in db fiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8be0a790d8172093a032602345038e8e

See a discussion on this
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=in-vs-exists-and-not-in-vs-not-exists

Answer (score 1):

As you have been answered by collegues you have to specify that you wanna return null values too.
Namely

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM EXPORT_BB 
    WHERE ISIN NOT IN (SELECT ISIN FROM EXPORT_BLACKLIST) 
    OR ISIN IS NULL;
```

Comment: Did you just copy the code from my answer and posted it as your code?

Comment: Nope. eheh it is very simple code for Oracle users, so it is normal codes are similar or look the same ;) It's like If I say you that you copy my code ideas if you write "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL'

Comment: Really? And why did you post it? Was it missing from this thread?